# Convert String to FontWeight in Java/JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

How can I convert a `String`, for example `"NORMAL"` (which is one kind of `FontWeight` in JavaFX) to the enum value `FontWeight.NORMAL`?

Comment: Are you asking to change the  text font weight in JavaFX? Like BOLD to NORMAL or NORMAL to BOLD

Comment: I want to convert "NORMAL" (String) into FontWeight.NORMAL, if you know what i mean

Comment: please add a [mcve]

Comment: Clarified that question is about getting the corresponding `enum` value for a given string.

Answer (score 0):

`FontWeight` is an enum and `NORMAL` is one of it's values. Therefore you can use the static method:

```
FontWeight.findByName("NORMAL");
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what i needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Every enum provides a `static` `valueOf` method that allows you to retrieve the enum constant given a `String` containing the identifier of that constant. The `FontWeight` enum is not different.

```
FontWeight weight = FontWeight.valueOf("NORMAL");
```